# Object.prototype and Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In JS functions are said to be objects. Now when functions are tested against objects, they behave differently.

```
a = {};
console.log(a.prototype);   //undefined

function myFunc() {};
console.log(myFunc.prototype); //Object
Object.getPrototypeOf(myFunc); //function(){}
```

And to make things worst, an example in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) seem to change the constructor of a function prototype.

> secondConstructor.prototype.constructor = secondConstructor;

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Hi, I cannot explain that behavior, but I can tell you to use typeof myFunc === "function" instead. on the other hand typeof {} === "object"

Comment: _"Can someone please explain this behaviour?"_ What exactly are you trying to demonstrate to us? Plain objects don't have a `.prototype` property. That doesn't mean that functions aren't objects.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm not trying to demonstrate anything - but rather waiting for someone to demonstrate me how the above disparity in objects is possible in JS. Please look at the answer from Maximus for more info.

Comment: What disparity? You have to explain in your question in words. Just showing us a lump of code isn't enough.

Comment: @JLRishe Again see the answer from Maximus if you still don't understand my question.

Comment: @CharlieH You didn't ask a question. People shouldn't have to read one of the answers to find out what your question is.

Comment: @JLRishe Please find the question mark in my text if you can't find the successful answer. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What leads to a common confusion is that a function as an object has `.__proto__` property and as a function has `.prototype` property. They have different meaning.

Most `JavaScript` objects have a prototype object, that can be accessed using `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method, or simply `.__proto__` property. This is the object which is used to reuse code and is consulted when a property accessor can't find requested property on an object, then it's looked up on its prototype. This is how common methods like `.apply` are available on a function.
This is how you access this object in your example:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(myFunc); //function(){}
```

Only functions have `.prototype` property, which is used by `new` operator when a new object is created using the function. When a function is called with `new` operator and a new object is created, JS checks the `.prototype` property of the function. If it points to an object, JS sets this object as a prototype of a newly created object. That's why the `.prototype` of an object in your example is `undefined`:

```
a = {};
console.log(a.prototype); // undefined
```

> Can someone please explain this behaviour?
>
> secondConstructor.prototype.constructor = secondConstructor;

The `constructor` property of an object usually points at the function that was used to create the object. When a function is declared, this property is created automatically on the object that `.prototype` property of the function points to.

```
function c() {}
c.prototype.constructor === c; // true
var o = new c();
o.constructor === c; // true
```

However, this property can easily be changed:

```
c.prototype = {constructor: function notCAnymore() {}}
var o = new c();
o.constructor === c; // false
```

Now we don't have a reference to the correct function anymore. So after changing the prototype, we may need to restore the `.constructor` property:

```
c.prototype = {constructor: function notCAnymore() {}}
c.prototype.constructor = c; // restoring the correct constructor
var o = new c();
o.constructor === c; // true
```

And that is exactly what is done in the example. The prototype is changed:

```
secondConstructor.prototype = new firstConstructor;
```

If object is created now the pointer to a correct constructor is lost:

```
var o = new secondConstructor();
o.constructor === secondConstructor; // false
```

That's why they use this code to restore it:

```
secondConstructor.prototype.constructor = secondConstructor;
var o = new secondConstructor();
o.constructor === secondConstructor; // true
```

Comment: Thanks. It explains the mystery. Also can you please cover some background about the MDN article setting the constructor in that manner?

Comment: Thank you very much. Very well explained.

Comment: @CharlieH, you're welcome. It's indeed a confusing topic.

Answer (score 1):

For your first statement

```js
var a = {};
console.log(typeof(a));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a));
```

Here a, is just an object ,when you check its type it just returns object and you cannot access its prototype

**All JavaScript objects inherit the properties and methods from their prototype.**

**Objects created using an object literal, or with new Object(), inherit from a prototype called Object.prototype**

Here in the first case, a is just object literal so its prototype is empty.

In the second case, myFunc is  a definition which objects can be created through new ,but it is also an object,so thats the reason the prototype is object here

**The Object.getPrototypeOf() method returns the prototype (i.e. the value of the internal [[Prototype]] property) of the specified object.**

For MyFunc the prototype is function because it has been defined as function

```js
function myFunc() {};
console.log(myFunc.prototype); //Object
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myFunc));
```

In the third snippet,It is the case of inheritance

```js
function parent(name){
this.name=name;
}

function child(childname){
this.childname=childname;
}

child.prototype=Object.create(parent.prototype);

console.log(parent.prototype);
console.log(parent.prototype.constructor);
console.log(child.prototype);
console.log(child.prototype.constructor);
```

When child is inherting parent,its prototype and constructor is parent,in order to change the constructor to be of the same  MDN has mentioned it as

```
child.prototype.constructor=parent;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: //Here in the first case, a is just object literal so its prototype is empty. This is wrong. The correct way of explaining this is that you cannot access the prototype of most of JS objects through "prototype" property.